# How to keep links visible after hovering

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I'm trying to have the links for AgentSheets, Gimp, and InkScape to show when the link for Portfolio is hovered.  I've achieved that, but whenever the mouse is moved from portfolio, to click one of the links, they disappear because Portfolio isn't being hovered over anymore.  Anyone have any advice?  Thanks!

CSS:

```
#portfolio:hover + #portfolio2 {
    display:block;
}

#portfolio2 {
    display:none;
}

#portfolio {
    width:70px;
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html" onClick="readCookie();">Portfolio</a>div>
<div id="portfolio2">
<a href="portfolio_Sim.html" onClick="readCookie();">Agentsheets</a>
<a href="portfolio_Gimp" onClick="readCookie();">Gimp</a>
<a href="portfolio_Ink" onClick="readCookie();">InkScape</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:none;` means whatever is in that div won't be visible.(http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_none) Do you mean that all other links disappear when you remove the mouse from the `portfolio` link?

Answer (score 1):

To have this effect work the `portfolio2` div should be inside the main div

**HTML**

```
<div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html" onClick="readCookie();">Portfolio</a>

    <div id="portfolio2">
<a href="portfolio_Sim.html" onClick="readCookie();">Agentsheets</a>

<a href="portfolio_Gimp" onClick="readCookie();">Gimp</a>

<a href="portfolio_Ink" onClick="readCookie();">InkScape</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Then the CSS becomes

```
#portfolio:hover #portfolio2 {
    display:block;
}
#portfolio2 {
    display:none;
}
#portfolio {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Note**: this **will** cause the parent div to change in size which may not be what you need.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dGdfR/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you used `display: inline` on the `#portifolio` div so the links would be sided. But that actually keeps your hovering to work well.

You can use `white-space: nowrap` instead, so the `<a>` links would remain inline. Also, remove the css `+` selector, because it is not for this scenario.

So your css code would be:

```
#portfolio:hover #portfolio2 {
    display:block;
}

#portfolio2 {
    display:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#portfolio {
    width:70px;
}
```

Also, you have to correct the html:

```
<div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html" onClick="readCookie();">Portfolio</a>
    <div id="portfolio2">
        <a href="portfolio_Sim.html" onClick="readCookie();">Agentsheets</a>
        <a href="portfolio_Gimp" onClick="readCookie();">Gimp</a>
        <a href="portfolio_Ink" onClick="readCookie();">InkScape</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3S82/

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution. Again, you must put the hidden DIV inside the visible one. And use this CSS, which maintains the desired (fixed) width of your elements:

```
#portfolio {
    width:70px;
    background: green;
}
#portfolio2 {
    display:none;
    width: 200px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#portfolio:hover > #portfolio2 {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLLQA/1/

Answer (score 0):

1.Your closing div after Portfolio < /a> is not closing properly.
2.You have to remove the second closing div at the end of the script.